# Can I write descriptions and notes into a diagram with Latex?

Tags: graphs

I just wanted to know if it is possible to write things into diagrams. I'm writing a scientific paper in German. So I need to edit a diagram by removing all English descriptions and writing them in German again.

To make the whole thing easier, I posted a graphic. [image]

As you see everything is in English. So I need to edit everything to become in German. And to get a good quality I think It's better to even write the labelling and the numbers on the axes myself.

Comment: You can place text and geometric elements on top of an existing image using [Drawing on an image with TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz). There might be more elegant ways to do this, though. What image format are your diagrams in (PNG, PDF, ...)?

Comment: Based on your question, are we to presume that you have access only to a graphic of the diagram (e.g., jpeg), but not to the original source (e.g., LaTeX, eps, etc.?)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes yes exactly. I'm just going to print paste it and edit in in gimp. But I would like to write everything in Latex, so that the quality would be good.

Comment: @Jake thank you, I'll bookmark the page you pasted. But since I'm not that much familiar with editing images in LaTeX, I think I still need some time to learn working with TikZ.

Answer (score 1):

Well, my suggestion is to use [Dia](http://dia-installer.de/), which of course, is free and is available in german as well.

With that program you'll be able to edit all the diagrams you want, plus the excellent side that you can export it to `PSTricks` and then, along with the `PSTricks` package (examples [here](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pstricks-examples)) you can generate the output with LaTeX

I would really suggest you start there.

PS: `Dia` Can also export to `TikZ/pgf` (See [here](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf)), `Metapost` (see [here](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/metapost)) and many others.  Feel free to experiment for a while to see what fits your needs the most.

Comment: Wow, that's very helpful thanky you. As for I just need to edit a diagramm (which is actually a .png image, since I took it from a pdf file) I think I'll just need to edit it with TikZ. But later I'm going to be in need for softwares like Dia so thank you. I suppose I can also import graphs from excel to Dia, then to TikZ and finally to Latex? Is this true? And do you have a way how I can optimize the quality of .png images to use them in Latex? I tried using imagemagick to sharpen them, but still didn't get the quality I want. I've also edited my question, please check.

Comment: @abdu Well, unfortunately no.  You cannot go excel-dia-tikz-latex.  For image editing I'll suggest you go with [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org).  Again, software gratis, available in german and it's the most powerful weapon I know for image editing.